# Does apache ignite create cassandra tables on startup or we need to run any command?

Tags: java, ignite

I have configured cassandra as a persistent store, How and when cassandra keyspeaces and tables are created by ignite ?

I started ignite but keyspace and tables are not created. Do I need to run any command or something ? or it should create keyspace and table on startup ?

I followed the documentation and example from https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/examples

```
public class CassandraDataSource implements Factory<DataSource> {

    @Override
    public DataSource create() {
        String[] contactPoints = {"localhost"};
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        return dataSource;
    }
}



public class RatioCacheConfig {

    /** Cache name. */
    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "RatioCache";

    /**
     * Creates cache configurations.
     * @param <K>
     * @param <V>
     *
     * @return {@link CacheConfiguration}.
     */
    public static <K, V> CacheConfiguration <K, V> cache(CassandraCacheStoreFactory<K, V> storeFactory) {

        CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration();

        cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(storeFactory);
        cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);

        cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Ratio.class);
        cacheCfg.setName(CACHE_NAME);

        return cacheCfg;
    }

}



String ratioPersistenceSettingConfig = "<persistence keyspace=\"ignite_view\" table=\"ratio\"><keyPersistence class=\"java.lang.String\" strategy=\"PRIMITIVE\"/><valuePersistence class=\"com.my.ignite.ratio.Ratio\" strategy=\"POJO\"/></persistence>";

KeyValuePersistenceSettings ratioPersistenceSetting = new KeyValuePersistenceSettings(ratioPersistenceSettingConfig);

CassandraCacheStoreFactory<String, Ratio> ratioStoreFactory = new CassandraCacheStoreFactory<>();   
ratioStoreFactory.setDataSource(new CassandraDataSource().create());
ratioStoreFactory.setPersistenceSettings(ratioPersistenceSetting);

try (IgniteCache<String, Ratio> ratioCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(RatioCacheConfig.cache(ratioStoreFactory))) {

}
```

Log:

```
>>> Starting timeseries cache loader...
Mar 16, 2017 8:13:59 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to resolve default logging config file: config/java.util.logging.properties
[20:13:59]    __________  ________________ 
[20:13:59]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[20:13:59]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[20:13:59] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[20:13:59] 
[20:13:59] ver. 1.9.0#20170302-sha1:a8169d0a
[20:13:59] 2017 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[20:13:59] 
[20:13:59] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[20:13:59] 
[20:13:59] Quiet mode.
[20:13:59]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[20:13:59] 
[20:13:59] OS: Linux 4.4.0-66-generic amd64
[20:13:59] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_91-b14 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.91-b14
[20:13:59] Initial heap size is 250MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[20:13:59] Configured plugins:
[20:13:59]   ^-- None
[20:13:59] 
[20:13:59] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[20:13:59] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[20:14:01] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
[20:14:01] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[20:14:01]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[20:14:01]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[20:14:01]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[20:14:01]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[20:14:01] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[20:14:01] 
[20:14:01] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[20:14:01] 
[20:14:01] Ignite node started OK (id=baf95d6d)
[20:14:01] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=3.5GB]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:336 - Setting default value: false
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:127 - Converting 'Boolean' value 'false' to type 'Boolean'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Boolean
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Byte'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:158 -     Converted to Byte value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:336 - Setting default value:  
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:127 - Converting 'Character' value ' ' to type 'Character'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Character
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Double'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:158 -     Converted to Double value '0.0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Float'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:158 -     Converted to Float value '0.0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Integer'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Integer
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Long'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:158 -     Converted to Long value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Short'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:158 -     Converted to Short value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigDecimalConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0.0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigDecimalConverter:127 - Converting 'BigDecimal' value '0.0' to type 'BigDecimal'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigDecimalConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a BigDecimal
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigIntegerConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigIntegerConverter:127 - Converting 'BigInteger' value '0' to type 'BigInteger'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BigIntegerConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a BigInteger
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:336 - Setting default value: false
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:127 - Converting 'Boolean' value 'false' to type 'Boolean'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG BooleanConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Boolean
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Byte'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ByteConverter:158 -     Converted to Byte value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:336 - Setting default value:  
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:127 - Converting 'Character' value ' ' to type 'Character'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG CharacterConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Character
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Double'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG DoubleConverter:158 -     Converted to Double value '0.0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Float'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG FloatConverter:158 -     Converted to Float value '0.0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Integer'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG IntegerConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Integer
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Long'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG LongConverter:158 -     Converted to Long value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:336 - Setting default value: 0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Short'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ShortConverter:158 -     Converted to Short value '0'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG StringConverter:336 - Setting default value: 
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG StringConverter:127 - Converting 'String' value '' to type 'String'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Z@303e3593
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'boolean[]' value '[Z@303e3593' to type 'boolean[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a boolean[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [B@4ef27d66
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'byte[]' value '[B@4ef27d66' to type 'byte[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a byte[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [C@362a019c
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'char[]' value '[C@362a019c' to type 'char[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a char[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [D@1d9bec4d
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'double[]' value '[D@1d9bec4d' to type 'double[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a double[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [F@5c48c0c0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'float[]' value '[F@5c48c0c0' to type 'float[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a float[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [I@10c8f62
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'int[]' value '[I@10c8f62' to type 'int[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a int[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [J@674c583e
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'long[]' value '[J@674c583e' to type 'long[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a long[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [S@25f7391e
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'short[]' value '[S@25f7391e' to type 'short[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a short[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.math.BigDecimal;@3f23a3a0
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'BigDecimal[]' value '[Ljava.math.BigDecimal;@3f23a3a0' to type 'BigDecimal[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a BigDecimal[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.math.BigInteger;@5ab14cb9
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'BigInteger[]' value '[Ljava.math.BigInteger;@5ab14cb9' to type 'BigInteger[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a BigInteger[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Boolean;@439a8f59
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Boolean[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Boolean;@439a8f59' to type 'Boolean[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Boolean[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Byte;@31024624
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Byte[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Byte;@31024624' to type 'Byte[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Byte[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Character;@32cb636e
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Character[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Character;@32cb636e' to type 'Character[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Character[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Double;@40dd3977
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Double[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Double;@40dd3977' to type 'Double[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Double[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Float;@6a1d204a
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Float[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Float;@6a1d204a' to type 'Float[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Float[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@4b6579e8
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Integer[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Integer;@4b6579e8' to type 'Integer[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Integer[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Long;@6c6357f9
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Long[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Long;@6c6357f9' to type 'Long[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Long[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Short;@3954d008
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Short[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Short;@3954d008' to type 'Short[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Short[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.String;@593e824f
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'String[]' value '[Ljava.lang.String;@593e824f' to type 'String[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a String[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.lang.Class;@72ccd81a
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Class[]' value '[Ljava.lang.Class;@72ccd81a' to type 'Class[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Class[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.util.Date;@6d8792db
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Date[]' value '[Ljava.util.Date;@6d8792db' to type 'Date[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Date[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.util.Calendar;@64bc21ac
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'Calendar[]' value '[Ljava.util.Calendar;@64bc21ac' to type 'Calendar[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a Calendar[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.io.File;@5d25e6bb
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'java.io.File[]' value '[Ljava.io.File;@5d25e6bb' to type 'java.io.File[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.io.File[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.sql.Date;@9d157ff
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'java.sql.Date[]' value '[Ljava.sql.Date;@9d157ff' to type 'java.sql.Date[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.sql.Date[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.sql.Time;@5df417a7
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'java.sql.Time[]' value '[Ljava.sql.Time;@5df417a7' to type 'java.sql.Time[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.sql.Time[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.sql.Timestamp;@7f69d591
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'java.sql.Timestamp[]' value '[Ljava.sql.Timestamp;@7f69d591' to type 'java.sql.Timestamp[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.sql.Timestamp[]
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:336 - Setting default value: [Ljava.net.URL;@61078690
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:127 - Converting 'java.net.URL[]' value '[Ljava.net.URL;@61078690' to type 'java.net.URL[]'
2017-03-16 20:14:01 DEBUG ArrayConverter:149 -     No conversion required, value is already a java.net.URL[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyspaces and tables are created on demand. Basically, when first interaction with the store happens, 'table not found' exception is thrown, Ignite catches it and create all required tables. So it's OK that they are not created yet when you just started a node.

Also you should make sure that the user Ignite connects with has enough permissions to create tables. If this is not possible, you can also use DDL generator to create schema manually based on your persistence configuration: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ddl-generator

Comment: I am not writing to cassandra from ignite, I have configured only read through. I will to loading data into cassandra from csv using some external command. I am trying to load ignite cache from cassandra on startup.

Comment: Also, for ddl generator,  I am embedding ignite into project, I am not using it as a standalone server. So cassandra module is embedded as dependency.   Not sure how to run ddl generator command in that case.

Comment: I'm confused. If you're loading from Cassandra, then you must already have all the tables filled with data it this point, right? Can you clarify this? If you're loading from CSV to Cassandra, then Ignite is involved at all, so you will have to manually create tables.

Comment: DDL generator is just a standalone program that converts ignite-cassandra persistence config into Cassandra DDL script. You can run this script to create keyspaces and tables, and then use original config with Ignite.